# Android how set different resource for different brand phone with xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-resources

Is there anyway to set different resource for phones of different brands?

For example, I need to get different drawable between Samsung and HTC phone.

I know that I can reach this with programmly, but is there anyway to reach this with XML only? Just like setting different resource for different locale.

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // code for fetch "brand_of_phone" or fetch it in Application.java
    // ...

    if(brand_of_phone.equals("samsung")){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brand_samsung);
    }else if(brand_of_phone.trim().contains("htc")){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brand_htc);
    }else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brand);
    }
}
```

Different brands use different layout file. Then you can setting different resource for different locale.

Comment: Actually, if they're doing it properly, they're using different themes in xml.

Answer (score 0):

There is no resource qualifier that you can use to differentiate phone brands.

The full list of resource qualifiers that you can use is available here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

The closest thing to what you're looking for is the second half of the first qualifier (the "mobile network code"), but that is to differentiate carriers, not brands.

Through Java, you can access the device's brand with the `Build.BRAND` constant.